# How to open SharePoint custom callouts on mouse hover instead of mouse click?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, callouts

I have created a custom SharePoint callout with the help of following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/callout.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getListItems,"callout.js");

        function getListItems() {
var Url = "SiteURL/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/AnnouncementList";
var request = new Sys.Net.WebRequest();
request.set_httpVerb("GET");
request.set_url(Url);
request.get_headers()["Accept"] = "application/json";
request.add_completed(onCompletedCallback);
request.invoke();
}

function onCompletedCallback(response, eventArgs) {
var announcements = eval("(" + response.get_responseData() + ")");
var newAnnouncement = document.createElement("div");
for (var i = 0; i < announcements.d.results.length; i++) {
            _announTitle = announcements.d.results[i].Title;
        _announID = announcements.d.results[i].Id;
_announBody = announcements.d.results[i].Body;
announcementsList.appendChild(newAnnouncement);
var calloutLink = document.createElement("div");
            calloutLink.id = _announID;
            calloutLink.onmouseover = function () {
            curListUrl = this.id; 
        }
calloutLink.innerHTML = "<div class=\"ms-commandLink\" style=\"text-align: left;font-size: 14px;\"><b>" + _announTitle + "</b><br /><br /></div>"; 
announcementsList.appendChild(calloutLink);
var listCallout = CalloutManager.createNew({
    launchPoint: calloutLink,
    beakOrientation: "leftRight",
    ID: _announID,
    title: _announTitle,
    content: "<div class=\"ms-soften\" style=\"margin-top:13px;\">"
    + "<hr/></div>"
    + "<div class=\"callout-section\" style=\"margin-top:13px;\">" + _announBody + "</div>",
}); 

}
}
</script >
    <div id="announcementsList"></div>
```

You can get this code from [here](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/wp-content/uploads/downloads/2013/06/Announcements_With_Details_in_Callouts.txt)

I am following [Display Item Details in a CallOut on Hover Over of Item Title in SharePoint 2013](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/05/30/display-item-details-in-a-callout-on-hover-over-of-item-title-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Here everything works fine, but the callout opens when I click the item, I want it to open when I hover the item.

Any suggestions?

**Edit**

Updated the code to remove the confusion.

Here I have already used

```
calloutLink.onmouseover = function () {
    curListUrl = this.id; 
}
```

Still it open when I click item.

Comment: can you try it as `<div id="showAnnouncementdiv" onmouseover="Javascript:getListItems();">Click Here to Display Announcements</div>` ?

Comment: Thanks, but that code is correct, that code just load all the item on button click. Problem starts when all items loads and when I hover to item it does not shows anything, but when I click item it shows expected callout..

Comment: That's because you have  href, instead of that you should be using `onmouseover` event . Check this link - https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_mouseover_mouseout

Comment: Updated the code to remove the confusion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following line is missing in your code :

```
       listCallout.set({openOptions:{event: "hover"}});
```

Try with the following code :

```
      var listCallout = CalloutManager.createNew({ 
            launchPoint: calloutLink,
            beakOrientation: "leftRight", 
            ID: _announID, 
            title: _announTitle, 
            content: "<div class=\"ms-soften\" style=\"margin-top:13px;\">" 
                    + "<hr/></div>" 
                    + "<div class=\"callout-section\" style=\"margin-top:13px;\">" + _announBody + "</div>", 
        }); 
   listCallout.set({openOptions:{event: "hover"}});
   }
```

It is working for me.
Let me know if you face any issues with this.

For more details refer this link:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn135236.aspx

Thanks!

Comment: Great.. It worked but still little problem. First time I have to click on the link, once callout opened with click, then next time it is opening on hover. I want to open it by hover from the first time onward. Thanks for the great link..

Comment: I checked this thing on multiple browser, even with the static data. Same happened all the time.

Comment: Yes, i have checked the same with static data but it seems to be its default behavior.

Comment: ok. So I am marking as answer because it solved the purpose. Thanks again saving my time. :-)

Comment: when we search anything in SharePoint, the search result opens callouts on hover of item. So, hover callout also works in SharePoint. default is not click behavior

Comment: ok. i will come back to this once i get some bandwidth from my work.

Comment: Got the solution, I just added `this.click();` in  `calloutLink.onmouseover = function () {  curListUrl = this.id; }` . So final code block was like `calloutLink.onmouseover = function () {    curListUrl = this.id; this.click(); } `

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution.

I just added `this.click()` in the following code block

`calloutLink.onmouseover = function ()
{
    curListUrl = this.id;
}`

So updated code looks like.

`calloutLink.onmouseover = function ()
{
    curListUrl = this.id;
    this.click(); // This line of code was missing
}`

So final code for custom callout is given below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/callout.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getListItems, "callout.js");
    function getListItems() {
        var Url = "SiteURL/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/AnnouncementList";
        var request = new Sys.Net.WebRequest();
        request.set_httpVerb("GET");
        request.set_url(Url);
        request.get_headers()["Accept"] = "application/json";
        request.add_completed(onCompletedCallback);
        request.invoke();
    }

    function onCompletedCallback(response, eventArgs) {
        var announcements = eval("(" + response.get_responseData() + ")");
        var newAnnouncement = document.createElement("div");
        for (var i = 0; i < announcements.d.results.length; i++) {
            _announTitle = announcements.d.results[i].Title;
            _announID = announcements.d.results[i].Id;
            _announBody = announcements.d.results[i].Body;
            announcementsList.appendChild(newAnnouncement);
            var calloutLink = document.createElement("div");
            calloutLink.id = _announID;
            calloutLink.onmouseover = function () {
                curListUrl = this.id;
                this.click(); // Only line that was missing in my code
            }
            calloutLink.innerHTML = "<div class=\"ms-commandLink\" style=\"text-align: left;font-size: 14px;\"><b>" + _announTitle + "</b><br /><br /></div>";
            announcementsList.appendChild(calloutLink);
            var listCallout = CalloutManager.createNew({
                launchPoint: calloutLink,
                beakOrientation: "leftRight",
                ID: _announID,
                title: _announTitle,
                content: "<div class=\"ms-soften\" style=\"margin-top:13px;\">"
                + "<hr/></div>"
                + "<div class=\"callout-section\" style=\"margin-top:13px;\">" + _announBody + "</div>",
            });
        }
    }
</script>
<div id="announcementsList"></div>
```

Got solution from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c0a25a9e-f5dd-4437-8809-d2311244d483/how-to-open-sharepoint-custom-callouts-on-mouse-hover-instead-of-mouse-click?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Comment: slick way of persisting.  Elsewhere MS code samples to create this behavior do not work, but this works great! +1

Answer (score 1):

I know its late to post but for someone who is looking for a answer.

The above marked answer correct to extend but will have issue it might work on second instance like once clicked then hover.

to have it hover from page load do the following inside the createnew method rather than using the set function

```
openOptions : {event: "hover", showCloseButton: true};
```

if not using teh create new function then put it above where you are defining the options

```
calloutOptions.openOptions = {event: "hover", showCloseButton: true};
```